# Number of ways of picking coloured balls from a box.

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math, combinations

A box has 14 balls, 7 black balls numbered from 1 to 7 and another 7 white balls numbered from 1 to 7. A person picks 2 balls at a time and repeats the process till box is empty.
Let n be the number of ways of drawing the balls such that when every time he picks balls of both the colours, the difference of the numbers appearing on them is at most one.

I tried to brute force the problem at first but it got too complicated. Then I tried looking for a recurrence but don't see anything.

Comment: What contest is this from?

Comment: @lulu Its from a mock test for college entrance exams in India.

Comment: Not a full answer, but it seems you can simplify the problem a lot by looking at the number of pairs (7-7, etc.) that you can draw. For example, for a valid draw you can't have an even number of pairs.

Comment: Edit to the above, I misread the question. It is still true that, for example, you can't have 6 pairs, but this might not be as useful as I thought.

Comment: Does the order the balls are drawn in matters? That is, if you draw 1 and 1 then 2 and 2, is that the same as drawing 2 and 2 then 1 and 1?

Comment: I suppose I also should have asked this before I answered, but is the drawer guaranteed to pick one black ball and one white ball each time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(x,y)$ represent selecting a black ball labeled $x$ and a white ball labeled $y$.

Think of the possible valid ways to select two balls - either $|x-y|=0$ or $|x-y|=1$. This means that we can draw either $(x,x)$, $(x,x+1)$, or $(x,x-1)$.

Now for a crucial fact: it is impossible to draw two pairs of balls $(x,x+1)$ and $(x+1,x+2)$ and still meet the criteria given in the problem. If you were to do this, then there would be a black $x+2$ ball and a white $x$ ball still in the mix without any valid partners. You *could* argue that you could still pick $(x+2,x+3)$, for example, but this would then leave you in the same situation but now with a black $x+3$ and a white $x$.

From this, we get the following:

> Of the set of balls composed of the black  and white $x$ and $x+1$ balls, the only valid drawings are $(x,x)$ and $(x+1,x+1)$, *or* $(x,x+1)$ and $(x+1,x)$.

From here, let's call a drawing of the form $(x,x)$ to be a *match*, and a pair of drawings of the form $(x,x+1)(x+1,x)$ a *switch*, notated as $S_x$. We can show easily that the maximum number of switches possible is 3.

We can now say that a switch is even if $x$ is even and a switch is odd if $x$ is odd. It should be clear that we cannot have a drawing that includes both $S_x$ and $S_{x+1}$.

With all this in mind, it's easy to see which drawings are possible, and in fact, the list may be manually exhausted. Let's notate a drawing as a string of switches with the understanding that if a ball is not mentioned then it has a match. Our possible valid drawings are:

- $1$ (all matches) (1 element)
- $S_1,S_2,S_3,S_4,S_5,$ and $S_6$ (6 elements)
- $S_1S_3,S_2S_4,S_3S_5,$ and $S_4S_6$ (4 elements)
- $S_1S_4,S_2S_5,$ and $S_3S_6$ (3 elements)
- $S_1S_5$ and $S_2S_6$ (2 elements)
- $S_1S_6$ (1 element)
- $S_1S_3S_5$ and $S_2S_4S_6$ (2 elements)

If the order that the pairs of balls are selected does not matter, then there are simply 19 different ways to pick the balls so that the criteria are met. If the order *does* matter, then there are $19\times 7!=95760$ ways.

Comment: I think you missed two cases S1S4S6 and S1S3S6 but your method does give the correct answer. The wording of the question really makes it look like you can pick balls of the same colour at a time but I'll just assume that its poorly worded.

Comment: @AarthBhardwaj oops! Good catch! Then there would be *21* ways if the order doesn't matter and *105840* if it does.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify the problem statement: We assume that at each step, one white ball and one black ball are drawn.  We require that the difference of the numbers on the two balls does not exceed $1$.

Let's say $\sigma(i)$ is the number on the black ball of the pair with the white ball numbered $i$, for $1 \le i \le 7$, so $\sigma$ is a permutation of $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$.  If the permutation is to be acceptable, we require $|\sigma(i) - i| \le 1$ for all $i$.  We would like to count the number of acceptable permutations.

More generally, define $a_n$ to be the number of permutations $\sigma$ of $\{1,2, \dots , n\}$ with $|\sigma(i) - i| \le 1$ for $1 \le i \le n$.  It's easy to see that $a_1 = 1$ and $a_2 = 2$, so suppose $n > 2$.  There are only two possibilities for $\sigma(n)$: $n$ and $n-1$.  If $\sigma(n) = n$, then $\sigma(1), \sigma(2), \dots , \sigma(n-1)$ can be any acceptable permutation of $\{1,2, \dots ,n-1\}$.  There are $a_{n-1}$ such permutations.  If $\sigma(n) = n-1$, then it must be that $\sigma(n-1) = n$, and then $\sigma(1), \sigma(2), \dots , \sigma(n-2)$ can be any acceptable permutation of $\{1,2, \dots ,n-2\}$.  There are $a_{n-2}$ such permutations.  So
$$a_n = a_{n-1} + a_{n-2}$$
for $n > 2$.  This recursion, together with the initial conditions $a_1=1$ and $a_2 = 2$, allows us to compute any value of $a_n$ we like.  It also shows that $a_n = F_{n+1}$, the $(n+1)$-th Fibonacci number.

In particular, the number of acceptable permutations in our problem is $a_7=21$.  Since the seven pairs can be drawn in any order, the number of possible sequences of draws is $21 \times 7!$.